# Facebook authentication through Nakama server in Unity3D game

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, facebook-authentication, nakama

Unable to Authenticate **Facebook** through **NakamaDB server** in Unity Game, there's no proper documentation in Authentication through Facebook in Heroic Labs's document section.

> https://heroiclabs.com/docs/authentication/#facebook

this the only thing which is available in Nakama docs.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: "Unable to Authenticate Facebook through NakamaDB server" - okay - so what would you like us to do?

Comment: if you can guide to any document or any example, it will be great help @Dai

Comment: Did you follow the instructions you linked-to? Did you add the Facebook SDK? **You haven't described the problem's technical details at all**. And please don't reply with "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

I had to authenticate device first with my deviceID and then follow [these](https://forum.heroiclabs.com/t/link-facebook-and-authenticate-facebook/238) steps.